# Is there anyway to create a new Scala object from a Java Class

Tags: scala, scala-java-interop

I have a number of use cases for this, all around the idea of interop between existing Java libraries and new Scala Code. The use case I've selected is the easiest I think.

**Use Case:**

I working on providing a JUnit Runner for some scala tests (so that I can get my lovely red / green bar in Eclipse)
The runner needs to have a constructor with a java class as a parameter. So in Scala I can do the following:

```
class MyRunner(val clazz: Class[Any]) extends Runner {
  def getDescription(): Description 
  def run(notifier: RunNotifier)
}
```

When I use either

```
@RunWith(MyRunner)
object MyTestObject
```

or

```
@RunWith(MyRunner)
class MyTestClass
```

then the runner is indeed instantiated correctly, and is passed a suitable class object

Unfortunately what i want to do now is to "get hold of" the object MyTestObject, or create a MyTestClass, which are both Scala entities. I would prefer to use Scala Reflection, but I also want to use the standard Junit jar.

**What I have done**

The following Stackover flow questions were educational, but not the same problem. There were the nearest questions I could find

- [How to create a TypeTag manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494788/how-to-create-a-typetag-manually)
- [Any way to obtain a Java class from a Scala (2.10) type tag or symbol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12901823/any-way-to-obtain-a-java-class-from-a-scala-2-10-type-tag-or-symbol)
- [Using Scala reflection with Java reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15712097/using-scala-reflection-with-java-reflection)

The discussion on Environments, Universes and Mirrors in http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/environment-universes-mirrors.html was good, and the similar documents on other scala reflection also helped. Mostly through it is about the Scala reflection.

I browsed the Scaladocs, but my knowledge of Scala reflection wasn't enough (yet) to let me get what I wanted out of them.

Edit:
As asked here is the code of the class that is being created by reflection

```
@RunWith(classOf[MyRunner])
object Hello2 extends App {

  println("starting")

  val x= "xxx"
}
```

So the interesting thing is that the solution proposed below using the field called MODULE$ doesn't print anything and the value of x is null

Comment: I found that     val instance = clazz.getField("MODULE$").get(null) works to get the object. It seems a little 'magical' is this the recommend way?

Comment: This question is very good http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020746/get-companion-object-instance-with-new-scala-reflection-api/11031443#11031443

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution works fine if you want to use plan old java reflection.  Not sure if you can use scala reflection given all you will have is a `Class[_]` to work with:

```
object ReflectTest {
  import collection.JavaConversions._
  def main(args: Array[String]) {    
    val fooObj = instantiate(MyTestObject.getClass())
    println(fooObj.foo)
    val fooClass = instantiate(classOf[MyTestClass])
    println(fooClass.foo)
  }

  def instantiate(clazz:Class[_]):Foo = {
    val rm = ru.runtimeMirror(clazz.getClassLoader())
    val declaredFields = clazz.getDeclaredFields().toList
    val obj = declaredFields.find(field => field.getName() == "MODULE$") match{
      case Some(modField) => modField.get(clazz)
      case None => clazz.newInstance()
    }
    obj.asInstanceOf[Foo]
  }
}

trait Foo{
  def foo:String
}

object MyTestObject extends Foo{
  def foo = "bar"
}

class MyTestClass extends Foo{
  def foo = "baz"
}
```

Comment: This works fine thank you. Now I have the instance, I suspect that I can use scala reflection from it rather than the class.

Comment: Unfortunately while this works, it doesn't call the code that instantiates the fields in the companion object. For example if I have val x=1 inside the companion object, java reflection on the instance created returns null.

Comment: Can you provide the structure of the two classes you mention here in your question so I can provide a solution?  Is this the class based example or the object based example?  Just want to see the class/companion relationship and what you want to happen so I can provide an answer.

Comment: I've updated the original post with the code of the class at the end. Thank you for the feedback and help

Comment: Try taking `extends App` off of your `object`.

Comment: Wow. Just wow. That worked. Now I just have to wonder why that worked. Talk about magic. Thank you for all the help

Comment: I'm not sure what the deal with `App` is in regards to reflection.  I generally stay away from `App`.